# compile file from file_pb.js to file.proto

Tags: grpc, proto, grpc-node

I know how could I compile from `file.proto` to `file_pb.js` using this command:

```
c:\protobuf\bin\protoc.exe --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. .\file.proto
```

But, how I can convert from `file_pb.js` to `file.proto`

Answer (score 1):

You are unlikely to find a tool that does what you are asking for. The process of compiling a `.proto` file to a programming language was not intended to be reversible. The intention is for the `.proto` file to be the "source of truth" that directly describes APIs and the structure of the messages.

Comment: Thanks for your comment